# make_shared<string> segment fault

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, gdb, pulsar

when I use make_shared, the program will coredump, even the line never been called. when I remove make_shared it works fine.

```
#include <pulsar/Client.h>
using namespace pulsar;
using namespace std;

void func() {
    shared_ptr<string> t = make_shared<string>("");;// when I add this line, this program will core(even this func never been called), after remove this line, this program works fine. use shared_ptr<string>t(new string("")) also works fine
}

int main(){
    ReportClient j;
    shared_ptr<string> t;
    Client client("pulsar://xxx");
    Producer producer;
    Result result = client.createProducer("topic_xxx", producer);
    if (result != ResultOk) {
        std::cout << "Error creating producer: " << result << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
}


g++ report_main.cpp  -I../libs/pulsar/include -lpulsar
```

coredump:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff5c325f4 in __memcpy_ssse3_back () from /lib64/libc.so.6
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.17-196.tl2.3.x86_64 libgcc-7.3.1-6.tl2.x86_64 libstdc++-7.3.1-6.tl2.x86_64 zlib-1.2.7-15.el7.x86_64
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff5c325f4 in __memcpy_ssse3_back () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x000000000040f247 in std::char_traits<char>::copy (__s1=0x7ffff487d028 "\270\247h", __s2=0x68a538 "\270\247h", __n=6666176)
    at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/../../../../include/c++/7/bits/char_traits.h:350
#2  0x000000000040fbf5 in std::string::_M_copy (__d=0x7ffff487d028 "\270\247h", __s=0x68a538 "\270\247h", __n=6666176)
    at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/../../../../include/c++/7/bits/basic_string.h:3363
#3  0x0000000000420c9a in std::string::_M_mutate (this=0x68a530, __pos=0, __len1=0, __len2=0)
    at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/../../../../include/c++/7/bits/basic_string.tcc:934
#4  0x00007ffff7b24437 in std::string::_M_leak_hard() () from /lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#5  0x00007ffff7b2451b in std::string::operator[](unsigned long) () from /lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#6  0x00007ffff6b6584e in pulsar::SharedBuffer::SharedBuffer (this=0x688ec0, size=65536)
    at /usr/src/debug/apache-pulsar-2.11.0-SNAPSHOT-src/pulsar-client-cpp/lib/SharedBuffer.h:221
#7  0x00007ffff6b652d6 in pulsar::SharedBuffer::allocate (size=65536)
    at /usr/src/debug/apache-pulsar-2.11.0-SNAPSHOT-src/pulsar-client-cpp/lib/SharedBuffer.h:62
#8  0x00007ffff6b48a18 in pulsar::ClientConnection::ClientConnection (this=0x688e00, 
    logicalAddress="pulsar://ss-share2-pulsar-discovery-1.tencent-distribute.com:6650,ss-share2-pulsar-discovery-2.tencent-distribute.com:6650,ss-share2-pulsar-discovery-3.tencent-distribute.com:6650", 
    physicalAddress="pulsar://ss-share2-pulsar-discovery-1.tencent-distribute.com:6650,ss-share2-pulsar-discovery-2.tencent-distribute.com:6650,ss-share2-pulsar-discovery-3.tencent-distribute.com:6650", executor=std::shared_ptr (count 6668440, weak -1) 0x7fffffffdd00, 
    clientConfiguration=..., authentication=warning: RTTI symbol not found for class 'std::_Sp_counted_ptr<AuthDisabled*, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>'
warning: RTTI symbol not found for class 'std::_Sp_counted_ptr<AuthDisabled*, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>'
std::shared_ptr (count 3, weak 0) 0x67afd0)
    at /usr/src/debug/apache-pulsar-2.11.0-SNAPSHOT-src/pulsar-client-cpp/lib/ClientConnection.cc:176
#9  0x00007ffff6c1dadc in pulsar::ConnectionPool::getConnectionAsync (this=0x687bf0, 
    logicalAddress="pulsar://ss-share2-pulsar-discovery-1.tencent-distribute.com:6650,ss-share2-pulsar-discovery-2.tencent-distribute.com:6650,ss-share2-pulsar-discovery-3.tencent-distribute.com:6650", 
    physicalAddress="pulsar://ss-share2-pulsar-discovery-1.tencent-distribute.com:6650,ss-share2-pulsar-discovery-2.tencent-distribute.com:6650,ss-share2-pulsar-discovery-3.tencent-distribute.com:6650")
    at /usr/src/debug/apache-pulsar-2.11.0-SNAPSHOT-src/pulsar-client-cpp/lib/ConnectionPool.cc:94
#10 0x00007ffff6b2ca2f in pulsar::BinaryProtoLookupService::getPartitionMetadataAsync (this=0x687ef8, topicName=warning: RTTI symbol not found for class 'std::_Sp_counted_ptr<pulsar::TopicName*, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>'
warning: RTTI symbol not found for class 'std::_Sp_counted_ptr<pulsar::TopicName*, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>'

    std::shared_ptr (count 2, weak 0) 0x688250)
    at /usr/src/debug/apache-pulsar-2.11.0-SNAPSHOT-src/pulsar-client-cpp/lib/BinaryProtoLookupService.cc:76
#11 0x00007ffff6bc6a24 in pulsar::ClientImpl::createProducerAsync(std::string const&, pulsar::ProducerConfiguration, std::function<void (pulsar::Result, pulsar::Producer)>) (this=0x687ae8, 
    topic="pcg_pcgptc8218943_cloudrenderpaascost/pcg_pcgptc8218943_cloudrenderpaascost/pcg_pcgptc8218943_cloudrenderpaascost", conf=..., 
    callback=...) at /usr/src/debug/apache-pulsar-2.11.0-SNAPSHOT-src/pulsar-client-cpp/lib/ClientImpl.cc:171
#12 0x00007ffff6b3bc5f in pulsar::Client::createProducerAsync(std::string const&, pulsar::ProducerConfiguration, std::function<void (pulsar::Result, pulsar::Producer)>) (this=0x7fffffffe140, 
    topic="pcg_pcgptc8218943_cloudrenderpaascost/pcg_pcgptc8218943_cloudrenderpaascost/pcg_pcgptc8218943_cloudrenderpaascost", conf=..., 
    callback=...) at /usr/src/debug/apache-pulsar-2.11.0-SNAPSHOT-src/pulsar-client-cpp/lib/Client.cc:65
#13 0x00007ffff6b3bab2 in pulsar::Client::createProducer (this=0x7fffffffe140, 
    topic="pcg_pcgptc8218943_cloudrenderpaascost/pcg_pcgptc8218943_cloudrenderpaascost/pcg_pcgptc8218943_cloudrenderpaascost", conf=..., 
    producer=...) at /usr/src/debug/apache-pulsar-2.11.0-SNAPSHOT-src/pulsar-client-cpp/lib/Client.cc:53
#14 0x00007ffff6b3b9fd in pulsar::Client::createProducer (this=0x7fffffffe140, 
    topic="pcg_pcgptc8218943_cloudrenderpaascost/pcg_pcgptc8218943_cloudrenderpaascost/pcg_pcgptc8218943_cloudrenderpaascost", 
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
    producer=...) at /usr/src/debug/apache-pulsar-2.11.0-SNAPSHOT-src/pulsar-client-cpp/lib/Client.cc:47
#15 0x000000000040eb9c in main () at test/report_main.cpp:30
```

when I debug use make_shared and not use make_shared program I found that:

1. if I delete make_shared line in func(), make_shared called by pulsar client will call allocator, and the data is write
2. if I not delete make_shared line in func(), make_shared called by pulsar client not call allocator, so the data is outofbound

1 - gdb info:

```
Breakpoint 1, pulsar::SharedBuffer::allocate (size=65536)
    at /usr/src/debug/apache-pulsar-2.11.0-SNAPSHOT-src/pulsar-client-cpp/lib/SharedBuffer.h:62
62          static SharedBuffer allocate(const uint32_t size) { return SharedBuffer(size); }
(gdb) s
pulsar::SharedBuffer::SharedBuffer (this=0x62fb70, size=65536)
    at /usr/src/debug/apache-pulsar-2.11.0-SNAPSHOT-src/pulsar-client-cpp/lib/SharedBuffer.h:221
221               capacity_(size) {}
(gdb) s
std::make_shared<std::string<unsigned long&, char> > () at /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/shared_ptr.h:614
614     /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/shared_ptr.h: 
(gdb) s
std::forward<char> (__t=@0x7fffffffd73f: 0 '\000') at /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/move.h:77
77      /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/move.h: 
(gdb) s
std::forward<unsigned long&> (__t=@0x7fffffffd720: 65536) at /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/move.h:77
77      /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/move.h: 
(gdb) s
std::allocator<std::string>::allocator (this=0x7fffffffd6ff) at /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/allocator.h:113
113     /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/allocator.h: 
(gdb) s
__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::string>::new_allocator (this=0x7fffffffd6ff) at /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/ext/new_allocator.h:79
79      /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/ext/new_allocator.h: 
(gdb) s
std::allocate_shared<std::string, std::allocator<std::string>, unsigned long&, char>(std::allocator<std::string> const&, unsigned long&, char&&) (__a=...) at /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/shared_ptr.h:598
598     /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/shared_ptr.h:
(gdb) s
std::forward<char> (__t=@0x7fffffffd73f: 0 '\000') at /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/move.h:77
77      /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/move.h: 
(gdb) s
std::forward<unsigned long&> (__t=@0x7fffffffd720: 65536) at /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/move.h:77
77      /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/move.h: 
(gdb) s
std::shared_ptr<std::string>::shared_ptr<std::allocator<std::string>, unsigned long&, char>(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, std::allocator<std::string> const&, unsigned long&, char&&) (this=0x62fb70, __tag=..., __a=...) at /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/shared_ptr.h:316
316     /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/shared_ptr.h:
```

```
Breakpoint 1, pulsar::SharedBuffer::allocate (size=65536)
    at /usr/src/debug/apache-pulsar-2.11.0-SNAPSHOT-src/pulsar-client-cpp/lib/SharedBuffer.h:62
62          static SharedBuffer allocate(const uint32_t size) { return SharedBuffer(size); }
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.17-196.tl2.3.x86_64 libgcc-7.3.1-6.tl2.x86_64 libstdc++-7.3.1-6.tl2.x86_64
(gdb) s
pulsar::SharedBuffer::SharedBuffer (this=0x62fb70, size=65536)
    at /usr/src/debug/apache-pulsar-2.11.0-SNAPSHOT-src/pulsar-client-cpp/lib/SharedBuffer.h:221
221               capacity_(size) {}
(gdb) n
218               ptr_(size ? &(*data_)[0] : nullptr),
(gdb) p *data_
$1 = '\000' <repeats 65535 times>
```

2-gdb info:

```
Breakpoint 1, pulsar::SharedBuffer::allocate (size=65536)
    at /usr/src/debug/apache-pulsar-2.11.0-SNAPSHOT-src/pulsar-client-cpp/lib/SharedBuffer.h:62
62          static SharedBuffer allocate(const uint32_t size) { return SharedBuffer(size); }
(gdb) s
pulsar::SharedBuffer::SharedBuffer (this=0x631b70, size=65536)
    at /usr/src/debug/apache-pulsar-2.11.0-SNAPSHOT-src/pulsar-client-cpp/lib/SharedBuffer.h:221
221               capacity_(size) {}
(gdb) s
std::make_shared<std::string<unsigned long&, char> > () at /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/shared_ptr.h:614
614     /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/shared_ptr.h: 
(gdb) s
std::forward<char> (__t=@0x7fffffffd73f: 0 '\000') at /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/move.h:77
77      /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/move.h: 
(gdb) s
std::forward<unsigned long&> (__t=@0x7fffffffd720: 65536) at /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/move.h:77
77      /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/move.h: 
(gdb) s
std::allocate_shared<std::string, std::allocator<std::string>, unsigned long&, char>(std::allocator<std::string> const&, unsigned long&, char&&) (__a=...) at /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/shared_ptr.h:598
598     /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/shared_ptr.h:
```

```
615     in /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/shared_ptr.h
(gdb) n
pulsar::SharedBuffer::SharedBuffer (this=0x631b70, size=65536)
    at /usr/src/debug/apache-pulsar-2.11.0-SNAPSHOT-src/pulsar-client-cpp/lib/SharedBuffer.h:218
218               ptr_(size ? &(*data_)[0] : nullptr),
(gdb) n
221               capacity_(size) {}
(gdb) p *data_
$7 = "h4c\000\000\000\000\000hX-\366\377\177\000\000hX-\366\377\177\000\000h\300\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\240\001\000\000\000\000\000\000"...<Address 0x665000 out of bounds>
(gdb) p size
$8 = 65536
(gdb) p data_->length()
$9 = 4209160
```

Comment: when your code has undefined behavior then adding or removing a seemingly unrelated line of code can change the behavior, because with or without the line the behavior is undefiend. The actual issue can be in code you did not post

Comment: Then probably there is some undefined behavior going on somewhere else in your code and it will just behave randomly

Comment: My guess would be that your code isn't complied against the same standard library as pulsar resulting in ODR violations and therefore undefined behaviour. Alternatively pulsar is maybe compiled with different settings to how you are using it?

Comment: I found that when I use make_shared outside pulsar it will segment fault. It may beacause compiled problem, How could I check if they  use the same standard library?@Alan Birtles